# How do you structure two nested lists in a sample Backbone.js todo list app?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm working on a sample ToDo list project in Backbone and I'd like to understand how the framework would prefer me to organize its views and models in the nested list scenario.

To clarify what I mean by that, my single-page Backbone app should display lists of ToDo lists. From the backend standpoint, there's a List resource and an Item (a single entry in a todo list) resource. Something along the lines of:

- **Monday chores**

  - Pick up the mail
  - Do the laundry
  - Pick up drycleaning
- **Grocery list**

  - Celery
  - Beef
  - You get the idea...

Since mine is a Rails 3.2 app, I'm vaguely following the Railscasts Backbone.js tutorial, so that's where I'm getting the current design from. I would love to know if I'm wildly off the Backbone-prescribed pattern, or if I'm on the right track!

I thus far have:

```
ListsIndex View                         //index of all lists
\-- ListsCollection
     \-- ListView / Model               //individual list
          \-- ItemsIndex View           //index of items in one list
              \-- ItemsCollection
                  \-- Item View / Model //individual todo item
```

The flow would be:

1. On router initialize, fetch() collection of lists on /lists backend route. On the 'reset' event for the collection part of ListsIndex, execute render() on each of the items in the collection, appending to the list index view template.
2. In the initialize method of each Item View (*is this where you'd wire-up the second level fetch?*) fetch() the items from the /lists/:id/items backend route into an ItemsCollection specific to that view.
3. In the same method, instantiate an ItemsIndex object and pass the collection into it. Once again, in ItemsIndex, have a 'reset' event handler for when the collection is populated, at which point it should render each fetched model from the item collection and append them to its own view.

I'm essentially taking the design of the List and mirroring it down one level to its items. The difference is that I no longer have a router to rely on. I therefore use the initialize method of ListView to a similar effect.

Yay / nay? Super wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR; 1) I would bootstrap your initial data instead of a fetch() reset(). 2) You can do a fetch in the initialize of a View as you need it. Or you could load the data at the start. Just remember that if you fetch in the init, the async nature won't have the data ready at render. Not a problem if you have a listener waiting for that sync/add/etc. 3) I don't know what you mean by itemIndex object but you can create objects and add to them collections as you need them. Or you can just bake the in at the start if you know all your lists are going to have a collection eventually. You can reset if you want (fetch automatically does this unless you give it option {add:true}) or just add them in one by one as they come in although reset(), remove prior views, render all views seems to be the common way people do things with a complete fetch().

I think it looks pretty good. The nice thing about Backbone is that you can do it many different ways. For example, your number 2 says to wire up a second fetch() from the view. You could do that if you want to lazy load. Or you could just grab all the data at app start before anything is done. It's really up to you. This is how I might do it.

This is how I might make an app like this (just my preference, I don't know that it's any better or worse or if its the same as you described.)

First I would create a model called ListModel. It would have an id and a name attr. This way, you can create many separate lists, each with their own id that you can fetch individually.

Each ListModel has an ItemsCollection inside of it. This collection has a url based on the ListModel it is a part of. Thus, the collection url for ListModel-1 would be something like /list/1

Finally you have ItemModel which is a resource id and text.

```
ListCollection
    ListModel  // Monday Chores
        ItemCollection
            ItemModel  // Mail
            ItemModel  // Laundry
            ItemModel  // Drycleaning
    ListModel  // Grocery
        ItemCollection
            ItemModel  // Celery
            ItemModel  // Beef
```

So in this little display you'll notice I didn't put anything to do with views in yet. I don't know if it's more of a conceptual thing but this is what the data hierarchy looks like and your views can be, should be totally independent of it. I wasn't exactly sure how you were including the views up above but I thought this might make it clearer.

As for defining these structures, I think two things.

First, I'd make sure my ListModel is defined in my collection. That way I can use the collection add(hash) to instantiate new models as I produce / add them.

Second, I would define the ListModel so that when one is created, it automatically creates an ItemCollection as a property of that ListModel object (not as an attribute).

So ideally, your ListModels would be like this:

```
ListModel.ItemCollection
```

Before the app initializes, I would bootstrap the data in and not fetch(). (This kind of addresses point 1 you make) Ideally, when your Backbone application starts it should have all the necessary data it needs from the get go. I would pass in the head some data like this:

```
 var lists = [listModel-1-hash, listModel-2-hash];
```

Now when the app fires up, you can instantly create these two lists.

```
var myLists = new ListCollection();

_.each(lists, function(hash) {
    myLists.add(hash);  // Assumes you have defined your model in the ListCollection
}
```

Now your List Collection has all the list models it needs.

Here is where views come in. You can pass in anything to any view. But I might break views down into three things.

AppView, ListModelView, ItemModelView and that's it.

Imagine a structure like this:

```
<body> // AppView
    <ul class="List"> // ListModelView
        <li class="Item"></li>     // ItemModelView
    </ul>
    <ul class="List"> // ListModelView
    </ul>
</body>
```

When your start your app and create an AppView, inside AppView you'd generate each ListModelView and append it to the body. Our lists are empty. Maybe when you click on the  it lazy loads the items. This is how you'd hook it up.

```
// In ListModelView
events: {'click':'fetchItems'}

fetchItems: function() {
    this.model.itemCollection.fetch();  // Assumes you passed in the ListModel into view
}
```

So since I bootstrapped the data to begin with, this fetch() call would be your "second" fetch. (I'm addressing point 2 you made.) You can fetch it in your initialize. Just remember that it is an asynchronous function so if you need them at render time, it won't work. But, what you can do is add event listeners to this view that are listening for add events to your itemCollections.

```
this.model.itemCollection.on('add', this.addItemView, this);
```

`addItemView()` will generate new instances of the itemViews and append them.

As for point 3, you can instantiate a collection at that point you need it and throw it into your ListModel. Or you can do what I did and make sure all your models always have an ItemCollection. This depends on your preferences and goals. You probably didn't need all this but I felt like illustrating it out for some reason. I dunno, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the super exhaustive explanation of your reasoning! I'll try to wrap my head around it and get back to you!

Comment: I like the approach of decoupling collections/models from the views, and of loading the data upfront as the app is loaded. I've implemented the lazy-loaded approach, but I feel it's somewhat messy. The other discovery I made is that, as you suggested, Backbone.js is completely unopinionated, and thus will let you get away with any organizational approach you prefer. That's a lot of rope to hang yourself with, so it's got to be used very judiciously.